# How do I add information to logs using AuthzReportSecurityEvent

Tags: c++, winapi, event-viewer, authz

I've got this CPP code that creates security logs using the  AuthzReportSecurityEvent function,I need to add a specific information to said logs but I can't figure out how to create the "Data Name" field and the information online is severely limited, I want to be able to add the
 information in the  part of the log.
This is the code that I have so far, I got it from another post about the subject:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Authz.h>
#include <Ntsecapi.h>


#pragma comment(lib,"Authz.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Advapi32.lib")

BOOL SetPrivilege(
    HANDLE hToken,          // access token handle
    LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege,  // name of privilege to enable/disable
    BOOL bEnablePrivilege   // to enable or disable privilege
)
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if (!LookupPrivilegeValue(
        NULL,            // lookup privilege on local system
        lpszPrivilege,   // privilege to lookup
        &luid))        // receives LUID of privilege
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    if (bEnablePrivilege)
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    else
        tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = 0;

    // Enable the privilege or disable all privileges.

    if (!AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        hToken,
        FALSE,
        &tp,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)NULL,
        (PDWORD)NULL))
    {
        printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)

    {
        printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    printf("Get the specified privilege! \n");

    return TRUE;
}




int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    // Declare and initialize variables.

    BOOL bResult = TRUE;
    DWORD event_id = 4624;
    AUTHZ_SECURITY_EVENT_PROVIDER_HANDLE hEventProvider = NULL;
    PAUDIT_PARAMS p;
    std::string Source_Name = "Test security audit";
    std::wstring ws;
    std::string pbuf = "What is your purpose ?";
    std::wstring ws_buf;
    int return_code = 0;
    int i = 0;
    // Register the audit provider.
    HANDLE token;
    HANDLE hevent_source;
    ws.assign(Source_Name.begin(), Source_Name.end());
    ws_buf.assign(pbuf.begin(), pbuf.end());

    if (!OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, &token))
        return FALSE;

    SetPrivilege(token, L"SeAuditPrivilege", true);

    AUTHZ_SOURCE_SCHEMA_REGISTRATION ar;
    memset(&ar, 0, sizeof(ar));
    ar.dwFlags = AUTHZ_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_SOURCE_INSTANCES;
    ar.szEventSourceName = &ws[0];
    ar.szEventMessageFile = &ws_buf[0];
    ar.szEventSourceXmlSchemaFile = NULL;
    ar.szEventAccessStringsFile = &ws_buf[0];
    ar.szExecutableImagePath = NULL;

    AuthzInstallSecurityEventSource(0, &ar);

    bResult = AuthzRegisterSecurityEventSource(0, ws.c_str(), &hEventProvider);
    int err = GetLastError();
    if (!bResult)
    {
        printf("AuthzRegisterSecurityEventSource failed, error is %d\n", err);
        return_code = -1;
    }

    SID id;
    if (hEventProvider)
    {
        // Generate the audit.
        while (i < 10) {
            bResult = AuthzReportSecurityEvent(
                APF_AuditSuccess,
                hEventProvider,
                event_id,
                NULL,
                3,
                APT_String, L"Jay Hamlin",
                APT_String, L"March 21, 1960",
                APT_Ulong, 45);
            int err1 = GetLastError();
            if (!bResult)
            {
                printf("AuthzReportSecurityEvent failed, error is %d\n", err1);
                return_code = -2;
                break;
            }

            i++;
        }

        AuthzUnregisterSecurityEventSource(0, &hEventProvider);
        AuthzUninstallSecurityEventSource(0, &ws[0]);
    }
    std::cout << "Exit  : " << return_code << std::endl;
    getchar();
}
```

I tried the AuthzReportSecurityEventFromParams function but there is little to no documentation for how to use it and I couldn't figure out if it's a better option or not

Comment: Looking at the function declarations and structures, I'm guessing that `AuthzReportSecurityEvent()` expects `Count` number of `AUDIT_PARAM` structs as the last parameters.

Answer (score 0):

As far as [`AuthzReportSecurityEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/authz/nf-authz-authzreportsecurityevent) is concerned, the function doesn't support to specify the name of variable arguments.
Also, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/93571/how-can-i-write-windows-security-log-using-authzre , It's by design. There is no entrance to specify the event data name.